# How to synthesize line breaks in GNU Make warnings or errors?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When using the b[uilt-in `$(error text)` and `$(warning text)` functions of GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions), how can I get line breaks into the error/warning output without acrobatics?

By acrobatics I mean funny methods such as these two:

```
$(warning $(shell /bin/echo -e "something\nfoo\nbar\nbaz"))
$(warning $(shell /bin/bash -c 'echo  -e "something\nfoo\nbar\nbaz"'))
```

which, btw, didn't work for me with GNU Make 3.81 on Ubuntu 10.04.

*Rationale:* I want to make the error output in conditional parts (`ifeq`, `ifneq`) of my `GNUmakefile` more readable.

---

The current workaround for me is to use for each line:

```
$(warning ...)
```

and finally for the last line:

```
$(error ...)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Define a line break variable using define/endef and use it as $n like this:

```
define n


endef

$(warning "something$nfoo$nbar$nbaz")
```

Note the two blank lines between define and endef

Comment: Both work, presumably because it's a single character?! Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. If it were nl instead of n it would have to be $(nl) or ${nl} to keep from being treated as ${n}l.  Single-letter variable names don't suffer from this problem in Gnu make.

Comment: Based on the response, I found I could just create a variable that is the message you want to display.