# Get make makefile warning output to include print newlines

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How do I get make to print out newlines with returned shell data?  I'm learning make by modifying a makefile.  Having newline come out as newlines would be nice.

```
# simple trial makefile
$(warning Making where CURDIR is $(CURDIR))
$(warning  $(shell ls -l $(CURDIR)))
```

I've seen a hint here.
[How to synthesize line breaks in GNU Make warnings or errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055773/how-to-synthesize-line-breaks-in-gnu-make-warnings-or-errors)

GNU Make 3.82

Robert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this.  The [`shell` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) clearly says that all newlines will be converted into spaces.  You cannot avoid this.

You could run a command and redirect the output to stderr, instead of stdout, so that it doesn't get captured by the `$(shell ...)` function:

```
$(warning Making where CURDIR is $(CURDIR))
$(shell ls -l $(CURDIR) 1>&2)
```