# Backslash-newline in a make variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which does something like this:

```
define finder
    find /usr/include /usr/local/include -name '*.h' \
    | xargs grep -in stupid
endef

all:

find:
    ${finder}

xfind:
    find /usr/include /usr/local/include -name '*.h' \
    | xargs grep -in stupid
```

The list of directories is actually much longer, which is why I'd like to break the line when it gets executed. `xfind` does exactly what I want:

```
$ make xfind
find /usr/include /usr/local/include -name '*.h' \
| xargs grep -in stupid
```

However, I'd like to use a [canned recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html), to use it for different targets; like the `finder` used in the `find` target. Unfortunately, `finder` is a variable and not a [recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Recipe-Lines.html), so [different rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Splitting-Lines.html) apply to it. When the recipe gets executed, everything is in one line.

```
$ make find
find /usr/include /usr/local/include -name '*.h' | xargs grep -in stupid
```

Is there a way to embed a backslash-newline into a variable in a way that survives until it is used as a recipe?

Comment: You want this so that the displayed command from make includes the newline? Or is there some other functional need for this?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes; I want a newline before the "xargs grep..." part so I can remember what it does, looking at the console output.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. It might be possible with sufficient game playing about values in variables and `$(value)` (and maybe `$(eval)`) but I'd have to poke at it a bit to try some things.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it *is* possible to embed a backslash-newline into a variable. The tricky thing was the backslash (took me a while to find the answer).

```
# variable containing a newline
# there must be two blank lines between the define and endef
# (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17055840/2064196)
define nl


endef

# variable containing a backslash
# https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/makefile.html#makefile.variables
# backslash !=           echo "\\"
# the version below avoids $(shell), as suggested by bobbogo's comment
backslash := \$(strip)
```

Now the canned recipe can be written as

```
define find
find /usr/include /usr/local/include -name '*.h' ${backslash}${nl} \
| xargs grep -in stupid
endef
```

and the output is the desired

```
find /usr/include /usr/local/include -name '*.h' \
 | xargs grep -in stupid
```

Comment: Yikes! BTW you don't need the `$(shell...)` in GNU make. Something like `backslash := \$(strip)` will work fine.